# Why can't I use assert with std::is_same?

Tags: c++, assert

Can somebody explain to me why on Earth does this code snippet refuse to work?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    assert(is_same<int, int>::value);
}
```

Compilation fails because, according to the compiler:

```
prog.cpp:7:33: error: macro "assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
  assert(is_same<int, int>::value);
                             ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:7:2: error: 'assert' was not declared in this scope
  assert(is_same<int, int>::value);
  ^
```

What? `is_same<int, int>::value` is undoubtedly *one* argument. Also `assert` *is* declared at this scope, and the compiler itself confirmed it in the previous error!

http://ideone.com/LcMVkn

Comment: Why not use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and alert the developer at compile time instead of runtime?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I’m trying to test my own code… and it’s not production anyway.

Comment: So? You're still going to get an error if something is wrong and it's far better to be informed during build time instead of dealing with the hassle of testing and waiting on runtime checking. You're doing the same thing but `assert` is the lessser of the two options here.

Comment: FYI, `assert` is a macro, and thus is not in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: After suggesting an alternative approach once, why don't you answer his question (or let someone else answer it)  rather than telling him why he shouldn't be asking the question.  Remember StackOverflow wants a MVCE.  Sometimes during the process of making it minimal you lose the motivation for doing it.

Comment: @DaleWilson You should probably re-read my comments because I never told the poster they shouldn't be asking the question. It's simply an alternative method that's considered a much better practice. As for letting someone answer the question you should check the timestamps and note that my comments were posted _after_ the question had already received a most glorious answer from πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I re-thought the problem and I now think that the reason for using the assert macro lied in my perception of the two constructs. Generally, I perceived the `assert` macro as intended to help me to find errors in my own code, but I perceived `static_assert` as a construct to intended for the users of my code, to prevent them from using my templated code incorrectly (therefore, having a similar purpose to exceptions like `std::out_of_range`, only compile-time). So, I’d put `static_assert` in production code, but use `assert` to debug my own non-production code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I understand my perception might’ve been wrong, however.

Comment: Well....developers use their own code incorrectly at times. If you have the option of alerting yourself as well as other developers to problems at _compile time_ then everyone knows they're (hopefully) using the code correctly. By using `assert` instead of `static_assert` you delay being alerted until the code is executed. What happens if you trip that exception on a _corner case_ in other code? Since the `assert` is compiled out in production the code may just blow up or worse appear to work correctly but cause issues in other code later on. Always catch problem as early as possible!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro splits your parameter(s) like this:

```
    is_same<int , int>::value
 // ^^ par1  ^^// ^^ par2  ^^
```

As `assert()` is a macro definition (with one parameter), it's handled by the C-preprocessor. The preprocessor is unaware of c++ syntax like template parameters gouped in angle brackets (`<>`) separated with `,`. So the parameter expression is split up like shown above.

You can avoid that using extra parenthesis, so the C-preprocessor will take that parameter as a whole:

```
assert((is_same<int, int>::value));
    // ^                        ^
```

Comment: So the answer is to type `assert((is_same<int, int>::value))`, right?

Comment: Is assert meant to work like that, or is it a bug in this particular implementation?

Comment: Also, why does this split happen? This is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: @gaazkam _"Is assert meant to work like that,"_ As it's handled by the C-preprocessor, yes.

Comment: @gaazkam _"Also, why does this split happen?"_ It's how the preprocessor works. Shrug.

Comment: The real answer is to type `static_assert(is_same<int, int>::value)`, as already suggested. Though this example is obviously contrived as `int` is always `int` :)

Comment: `assert` in `<cassert>` is defined as a C macro, so that when assertions are disabled, the argument doesn't get compiled (it is removed by the preprocessor). If it were an inline function, the argument would always have to be evaluated. But the preprocessor is from C and doesn't support all of the C++ specific syntax, like the `<int, int>`.

Comment: @Lightness The _real_ real answer is, that the C-preprocessor doesn't parse c++ code, and fails on template types with multiple type parameters.

Comment: C code has the same problem: the preprocessor only recognizes parentheses. `assert(a[1, 1]);` is an error, likewise for compound literals. It's just far more pronounced in C++.

Comment: It's because the preprocessor accounts for nesting of parentheses, but not other bracket types such as `<>` seen in this question, or `[]` square brackets mentioned by T.C., or even `{}` braces.  In some ways ignoring these bracket types is annoying, in other ways it is useful (you can pass a mismatched group -- because macros work on token streams, not expressions, you can do things with them that inlined functions can't duplicate).